# Generate 2D openpose skeleton from BVH animated skeleton

Tags: animation, 2d

I am a newbie in Blender, and didn't find similar questions.

I have to solve the following task:

1. I have a .bvh file with a single person skeleton. I can map bones (retarget) and get fbx animation from it.
2. From this animation I need to generate a sequence of images with 2D skeleton (openpose format) to use it in Stable Diffusion ControlNet. So, it is like regular render, but the output is openpose skeleton.

Obviously, I can run openpose pose detection directly from a rendered video of this animation (for instance, in fbx format), but the quality is not good in this approach.

But, it sounds like simple projection task and formats problem.
Can I do this using this addon for Blender: https://github.com/tin2tin/Pallaidium?

Any ideas are welcome!